# Write int value into an array of bytes

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this array : `BYTE set[6] = { 0xA8,0x12,0x84,0x03,0x00,0x00, }`  and i need to insert this `value : "" int Value = 1200; ""` ....on last 4 bytes. Practically to convert from int to hex and then to write inside the array...
Is this possible ?

I already have `BitConverter::GetBytes` function, but that's not enough.

Thank you,

Comment: Is memcpy what you want?

Comment: Are you intending to grow `set` from 6 bytes to 10, or just replace the last 4 bytes?

Comment: You haven't mentioned whether you want it stored in big or little endian, and it *will* make a difference

Comment: @WhozCraig it is not clear why it should be converted to hex? Another possibility is that he wants individual digits to be inserted to these 4 bytes ...

Comment: @ondav yeah, ambiguity seems to be in good swing. there a multiple answers on SO for converting signed and unsigned int values to byte arrays, but for them to be truly applicable a little more clarity in the question would be nice, to be sure.

Comment: @user2558921 please tell us how the resulting array should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer original quesion: sure you can. 
As soon as your `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(BYTE) == 1`.

But I'm not sure what you mean by "converting int to hex". If you want a hex string representation, you'll be much better off just using one of standard methods of doing it.
For example, on last line I use std::hex to print numbers as hex.

Here is solution to what you've been asking for and a little more (live example: http://codepad.org/rsmzngUL):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int value = 1200;
    unsigned char set[] = { 0xA8,0x12,0x84,0x03,0x00,0x00 };

    for (const unsigned char* c = set; c != set + sizeof(set); ++c)    {
        cout << static_cast<int>(*c) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Putting value into array:" << endl;
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&set[2]) = value;

    for (const unsigned char* c = set; c != set + sizeof(set); ++c)    {
        cout << static_cast<int>(*c) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Printing int's bytes one by one: " << endl;
    for (int byteNumber = 0; byteNumber != sizeof(int); ++byteNumber) {
        const unsigned char oneByte = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&value)[byteNumber];
        cout << static_cast<int>(oneByte) << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Printing value as hex: " << hex << value << std::endl;
}
```

UPD: From comments to your question:
  1. If you need just getting separate digits out of the number in separate bytes, it's a different story.
  2. Little vs Big endianness matters as well, I did not account for that in my answer.

Comment: This is the simple way to write a new value inside an array :

    BYTE byt[16]={0xC7,0x80,0xEA,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x8B,0xE5,0x5D,0xC2,0x08,0x00 };

  int value = 300;
  int tmp = value;
        for( int i=6 ; i<10 ; ++i )
  {
   myArray [i] = ( tmp & 0xFF );
   tmp = tmp >> 8;
  }
This will rewrite with the int value,the 6th,7th,8th,9th byte from the array.
Awesome :D...I can't answer to my own question right now...if anyone is kind to post the answer in the proper format....Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

did you mean this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTE unsigned char

int main ( void )
{
 BYTE set[6] = { 0xA8,0x12,0x84,0x03,0x00,0x00, } ;

 sprintf ( &set[2] , "%d" , 1200 ) ;

 printf ( "\n%c%c%c%c", set[2],set[3],set[4],set[5] ) ;

 return 0 ;
}
```

output :

**1200**

Comment: Has errors....Source.cpp(18): error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned char *' to 'char *'. I have solved the problem. Thank you,